# No route matches [POST] - Adding route does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

My method does not work.

I have a games library, where I can add, show, edit, and destroy. I want to expand it and add one more method `clone` to it.

Library created with `rails g scaffold`:

## The clone method in games_controller.rb

```
def clone
  @game.clone

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to games_url, notice: 'Game was successfully cloned.'}
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

## The call code for Clone in index

```
<% @games.each do |game| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= game.title %></td>
    <td><%= game.description %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', game %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_game_path(game) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', game, method: :delete, data: { confirm: '.. sure?' } %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Clone', game, method: :clone, data: { confirm: '.. sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

## The routes code in routes.rb

```
resources :games do
  resources :comments
  post 'clone'
end
```

[a view in games library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3vVJ.png)

Comment: @sawa Your edit is invalid and overrides the original content. Please see the edit history

Comment: @Pavan Sorry, it was Said Kaldybaev who changed OP's code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You have `method: :clone` which is **not valid**. The valid values for `method` option for [*`link_to`*](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) are *post, patch, put and delete*.

> method: symbol of HTTP verb - This modifier will dynamically create an
>   HTML form and immediately submit the form for processing using the
>   HTTP verb specified. Useful for having links perform a POST operation
>   in dangerous actions like deleting a record (which search bots can
>   follow while spidering your site). **Supported verbs are :post, :delete,
>   :patch, and :put**. Note that if the user has JavaScript disabled, the
>   request will fall back to using GET. If href: '#' is used and the user
>   has JavaScript disabled clicking the link will have no effect. If you
>   are relying on the POST behavior, you should check for it in your
>   controller's action by using the request object's methods for post?,
>   delete?, patch?, or put?.

Now coming to your routes, when you do `rake routes`, you will see the below

```
game_clone     POST   /games/:game_id/clone(.:format)     games#clone
```

So, the `link_to` should look like below

```
<%= link_to 'Clone', game_clone_path(game), method: :post, data: { confirm: '.. sure?' } %>
```

> Couldn't find Game without an ID

Ok, you are cloning a `Game` instance. Normally you look for an instance with an `:id`, but with your current routes, the `:game_id` will passed in the `params` which is not appropriate to want you need. You should change your routes to pass `:id` instead of `:game_id`. So the final solution will be

**Final Solution:**

```
resources :games do
  resources :comments
  post 'clone', on: :member
end
```

The above will create a path helper with the below

```
clone_game POST   /games/:id/clone(.:format)    games#clone
```

Now change the `link_to` with the new path helper and you are good to go

```
<%= link_to 'Clone', clone_game_path(game), method: :post, data: { confirm: '.. sure?' } %>
```

**Note:**

You should be careful when adding *custom routes* to your resourceful routes. This will create path helpers with unnecessary keys such as `:*_id`(`:game_id` in your case). These routes should be added as *collection route* or a *member route* depending upon the scenario. For more info refer these [*guides*](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)

Comment: Hi and thank you, i just tried it but it didnt work. now i have error like: Couldn't find Game without an ID.   

    def set_game
      @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    end

Comment: @HenrikZakaryan Ok, now see the params in the server log when you click on clone link. Copy it and and paste in your question.

Comment: @HenrikZakaryan I've updated my answer explaining why the problem is happening. Try my **final solution**, it should fix your problem

Comment: Thx Pavan it works but i dont see the cloned object in Library. How can i show it?

Comment: @HenrikZakaryan Thats another problem which you should ask by posting another question. For now, your current problem is solved :)

Comment: thank you very much and one question more. When i click "clone" it shows e message like "Game was successfully cloned" but i think it didnt clone. How can i check it? i tried with abord(game).